# Conditionally Display TabPanels?

Tags: c#, tabcontainer, tabpanel

Just wondering if this is possible or not:

Say I've got a TabContainer with 2 panels in there.  In most situations, I'd want the user to have the ability to select which tab to view.

Now, in a handful of scenarios, one of those TabPanels will not be visible, or empty.  Is it possible to make it so that in these situations, the entire TabContainer becomes "invisible"?  (i.e. the headers are not visible, and only the populated tab panel displays)

Ideally, I'd like to do this using the ajax TabContainer, but if this isn't doable; I can always fall back to using jQuery/CSS if need be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and quite doable. It's straightforward if you put the contents of the tab page that you want to show/hide in the dynamic manner that you describe into a separate user control. Then all you have to do is change the parent container of this control from the tab page to the control that is hosting the tab container, while also hiding the tab container.

Comment: Very nice solution, but I appear to hit a bit of a snag.  I wrapped the entire contents of a TabPanel in a asp:Panel so I could easily move it.  However, one of these contains an UpdatePanel, and I got the following error:  "Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'updBucketOrderer' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added again, which is not supported."

Comment: Haven't found a workaround as of yet; but I'm still rooting around, so we'll see what happens.

Comment: Interesting. Are you moving the contents programmatically or at design time. Seems like if you did it at design time this error should not come up. I could see how it could occur at runtime though. Which way are you doing it?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to do it in Page_Init().  This is an update panel nightmare, I've actually got code in there now to properly set up some trigger controls (since they're in different naming containers), so I'm half working on trying to get around the issue above, and half trying to see if I can hide the TabStrip if only one of the two tabs are visible.

Comment: Looks like I might be getting somewhere; this post:  http://kruegerwebdesign.com/blog/?p=44 appears to be a suitable workaround.  Now just to test a bit...

Comment: Wow. Ugly! Hope it works for you! (Pesky in this case is an understatement.)